# Twig table issues using craftcms

Tags: twig, content-management-system, craftcms

I am new to craft and twig and am trying to access table values inside of a neo matrix and started running into some blockers. I don't know how to query the values properly I think. Here is my code:

```
{% if row.tableColumn|length %}
  <table>
    {% set policyTable = row.tableColumn.all() %}
    {{ dump(row.tableColumn.all()) }}
    {% for row in policyTable %}
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            {{ row.col1 }}
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{ row.column1 }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% endif %}
```

And here is the dump for reference (shortened):

> array(1) { [0]=> object(craft\elements\MatrixBlock)#2695 (67)
> {["genericRichTextOnlyListItems"]=> NULL ["tableColumn"]=> string(402)
> "[{"col1":"THEAD1","col2":"THEAD2","col3":"THEAD3","col4":"THEAD4"},{"col1":"ROW1","col2":"60-75","col3":"15-30","col4":"5-20"},{"col1":"ROW2","col2":"45-55","col3":"35-45","col4":"5-20"},{"col1":"ROW3","col2":"5-15","col3":"75-85","col4":"15-25"}]"
> } }

I am trying to access `col1` in tableColumn which I have named `column1` on the craft backend. `{{ row.col1 }}` and `{{ row.column1 }}` will not work. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `policyTable` is an array of [Matrix Blocks](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/matrix-blocks.html). Each array item (though there's only one) has the table columns under the key `tableColumn`, so you can try something like this (I renamed `policyTable` to `policyTables` since it's an array):

```
{% if row.tableColumn|length %}
  <table>
    {% set policyTables = row.tableColumn.all() %}
    {% for row in policyTables[0].tableColumn %}
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            {{ row.col1 }}
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{ row.col2 }}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- etc. -->
      </thead>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% endif %}
```

Or if it's possible that there's more than one matrix block, you could try something like this:

```
{% if row.tableColumn|length %}
  {% set policyTables = row.tableColumn.all() %}
  {% for table in policyTables %}
    <table>
      {% for row in table.tableColumn %}
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              {{ row.col1 }}
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{ row.col2 }}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- etc. -->
        </thead>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In both cases, you probably want to handle the first row differently since it seems to be the heading row. You can utilize [Twig's loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) for this. (There might be some other ways as well.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Turns out `json_decode` is not needed though (i'm going to look into why). If you edit your answer and remove json decode I can accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @brooksrelyt Thanks, I updated my answer. Glad to hear you got it working!